# alert is being called before other events under chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Im doing a simple task with javascript on chrome Version 55.0.2883.87m:

```
document.body.style.background = "red";
alert("changed");
```

but the alert box is being executed before the change color event,
i have tried this on firefox and it works as expected, but not on chrome.
A fast hack i found is to warp the alert box in a setTimeout:

```
document.body.style.background = "blue"; 
setTimeout(function(){alert("changed");}, 0);
```

Anyone have any explanation why this is happening?

Comment: browser needs time to repaint the dom

Comment: @charlietfl firefox dosnt?